# gnome doesnt ask my password at login (DEBIAN 9)

Tags: linux, debian, passwords, login, gnome

I tried to use my fingerprint reader on my laptop yesterday, installing fprintd ; it didnt work...  ( *I removed all those packets* )

I then realized Gnome doesnt ask my password anymore at login screen, wether I set it on **ON** or **OFF** in gui parameters.

Could anyone tell me how to change this setting in a terminal ? 
Didn't find this info on the web :(

Comment: Try `apt-get purge fprintd`.

Comment: already did ; the settings have been modified, and the uninstall didnt set it back to normal ...

Answer (score 0):

**answer found here** : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401205/debian-how-to-set-login-behaviour-ask-passsword?noredirect=1#comment716669_401205

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```